# build with multi page don't work with vite 2.6 and vue 3.2

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I made a simple multipage app with vue 3.2 and vite 2.6

```
|-src
|---main.js
|-package.json
|-vite.config.js
|-index.html
|-validation_password.html
```

But when I want to build it: vite build only the index page (and not the validation-password).
I tried to modify my vite.config.js with rollup Options like [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) :

```
const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        valpass: resolve(__dirname, 'validation_password.html')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

the build failed. and i have this error in my terminal:

```
[rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Unexpected token (1:0)
file: C:/wamp64/www/IMB/VueJS/vuejs/src/PassVal.vue:1:0
error during build:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:19495:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:16820:8)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseExprAtom (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18870:10)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseExprSubscripts (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18662:19)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseMaybeUnary (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18628:17)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseExprOps (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18561:19)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseMaybeConditional (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18544:19)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseMaybeAssign (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18512:19)
    at Parser.pp$4.parseExpression (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:18476:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\wamp64\www\IMB\VueJS\vuejs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:17010:45)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! components-portail-math@0.0.1 build: `vite build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the components-portail-math@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\willb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-07T14_34_53_913Z-debug.log
```

My PassVal.vue file break no worries locally.
I don't understand. I'm following the doc.

Comment: What does this mean: *"My PassVal.vue file break no worries locally"*? What are the contents of `PassVal.vue`? Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: "locally" is when i used the command "vite serve" to preview my app locally in my browser. (sorry i'm french ;) )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Vue Router(I didn't know) to solve my problem.